# Based on Genesis 6:15-16, Could an adult male Giraffe (18-feet tall) actually stand in the 15-ft tall decks of the multi leveled 30-Cubit Ark?

Tags: genesis, noah, plants-and-animals

Male Giraffes are kosher land animals (chew cud, split hooves) whose height reaches 18-ft height (above a Female Giraffe's 15-ft height). [https://www.pbs.org/wnet/nature/blog/giraffe-fact-sheet/#]

If the Height of Noach's Tevah תֵּבָה "Ark" was built exactly "30-Forearms" (Cubits) שְׁלשִׁ֥ים אַמָּ֖ה Sheloshim Amah = 45-Feet tall, as stated in Bereshit 6:15.

> [Bereshit | Genesis 6:15]
> "And this [is the size] you shall make it: three hundred cubits the length of the ark, fifty cubits its breadth, and thirty cubits its height." (וְזֶ֕ה אֲשֶׁ֥ר תַּֽעֲשֶׂ֖ה אֹתָ֑הּ שְׁל֧שׁ מֵא֣וֹת אַמָּ֗ה אֹ֚רֶךְ הַתֵּבָ֔ה חֲמִשִּׁ֤ים אַמָּה֙ רָחְבָּ֔הּ וּשְׁלשִׁ֥ים אַמָּ֖ה קֽוֹמָתָֽהּ)

And נֹ֑חַ Noach divided הַתֵּבָ֖ה Ha-Tevah "The-Ark" into three separate decks, as stated Bereshit 6:16.

> [Bereishit | Genesis 6:16]
> "You shall make a skylight for the ark, and to a cubit you shall finish it to the top; And the entrance of the ark you shall place in its side. - Make it with bottom, second, and third decks." ( צֹ֣הַר | תַּֽעֲשֶׂ֣ה לַתֵּבָ֗ה וְאֶל־אַמָּה֙ תְּכַלֶּ֣נָּה מִלְמַ֔עְלָה וּפֶ֥תַח הַתֵּבָ֖ה בְּצִדָּ֣הּ תָּשִׂ֑ים תַּחְתִּיִּ֛ם שְׁנִיִּ֥ם וּשְׁלִשִׁ֖ים תַּֽעֲשֶֽׂהָ)

- Then Noach could not have equally divided the 30-Cubit tall Tevah into exactly three separate 10-Cubit decks (each measuring 15-feet high) - if an adult male Giraffe (over 15-ft tall) were to comfortably stand. (Correct?)

**Based on Genesis 6:15-16, Could an adult male Giraffe (18-feet tall) actually stand in the 15-ft tall decks of the multi leveled 30-Cubit Ark?**

Comment: This question is based on several unverified assumptions: (1) that there were no spaces taller than 15 cubits, (2) that animals were the same size then as now, (3) that Noah had full-grown adult specimens in the ark.  Any of these may and probably were untrue.  In short - we do not know.

Comment: In hindsight, my answer assumed the question was "how did they fit", but there are still scenarios where they were able to stand. :)

Comment: Why does the poor giraffe have to stand for a whole year ? ? ? Let the poor beast lie down and sleep (hibernate) for the whole journey. And it can bow its head and enter a space of less than ten feet.

Comment: @NigelJ - Giraffes often sleep [Standing]. -

Comment: Am I missing something? Where, in scripture does it say the three decks had to be of equal height? A 45ft high ark (450 ft long and 75 ft wide) could have had various heights of decks. If two were 10ft high each, that would have left room for a 25ft high deck.

Comment: @Anne - Please offer your 10-ft, 10-ft, 25-ft deck theory as an answer (or even icrements of 10-ft, 15-ft, 20ft - when considering elephants for the 15-ft deck). | These calculations help validate scripture.

Comment: @ 
חִידָה
I merely asked a question in the form of a comment, mentioning how different permutations could result in varying deck heights. I'm not answering the question, just expressing bewilderment as to why, in the Q, someone thinks all three decks had to be the same height. Even a blind man on a galloping horse could 'see' that varying deck heights could be fitted into a 45 feet high space!

Comment: The elephants, and other heavy animals were probably located on the bottom floor to act as ballast. The lighter animals would be higher up. One can imagining the giraffes being located somewhere in the middle, on the top floor, with their heads sticking out through an open roof window. Since they were clean animals there would have been 14 of them so they would have to take turns stretching their necks. The monkeys, and other high climbers probably would take their chance to climb on the giraffes necks in and out of the widow, between down-bursts.

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means an exhaustive list of scenarios where Scripture holds true, but there are many scenarios where if we assume the ark was exactly 45ft feet and the giraffes were 18ft, we can still cram them in.

###### Case 1

The giraffes live in the transition space such as:

- the ladder shaft
- the sloped ramps between decks
- the pulley room (retro elevator shaft)

###### Case 2

If you assume that there was be a central walkway like in a multi-story US prison, they could have had an enclosure in the walkway.

###### Case 3

The decks were not uniform in height, with at least 1 deck being large enough to accomodate them.

###### Case 4

The giraffes were only given 15 feet, yet they survived without ever drawing themselves up to their full height.

###### Case 5

There were enclosures that spanned 2 decks (a hole in the roof) for that cell of the ark.

###### Case 6

The giraffes had sloped windows that kept the rain sloping away from the ark. They used the window to draw themselves up to their full height on occasion. Personally, I believe case 6 is the truth.

###### Case 7

The giraffes rode on the roof (alright this one is a joke, but how amazing would that be?)

###### Conclusion

It is absolutely possible that 18ft giraffes can be successfully placed in a 45ft vessel.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you suppose that any of the animals were full grown adults?  Would it not be far better to take onto the ark creatures whose full adult life is still ahead of them?

Younger animals would need less food and drink and be better able to fill the earth with offspring after the Flood.

Comment: In particular, would you want to share a cramped space with 14 young calves, or with 7 cows and 7 full grown bulls?